# what is the triangle component in electronics?

Tags: digital-logic, components, logic-gates

From the following image we can see 3 triangle symbols:

[image]

looking to the triangle to the right i suppose it is a voltage buffer, but the ones at the left have 2 inputs. What are they?

This image is from a xx555 Precision Timers datasheet

Comment: Those are simplified op amp symbols

Comment: Hmm I was thinking that the Set/Reset lines are triggered to go high or low, based on some analog input voltage on pin 6 or pin 2

Comment: You should always link to your source so readers can check the context if they want to. In this case it looks like the internals of a 555 timer.

Comment: The right triangle symbol is just an inverting buffer; the left ones are comparators, which are often drawn as triangles with `+` and `−` symbols (just like OpAmps), but in this circuit diagram the `−` input is marked with a ring instead...

Comment: @Transistor yes it is from the internals of a 555 timer, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Triangles are shown for voltage, current or power amplifiers.**

The circle shows voltage inverting and may be an input for a differential amp or an inverting current buffer.

Not here but when the circle is shown on the output, it is normally used for inverting logic outputs as well as logic inputs. Also not here but a differential output might be shown with one of the outputs with a circle for a polarity reference to the input.

Below is the discrete schematic and I colour-coded the equivalent zones, so that you can understand how this 555 linear IC was drawn in both a "block-diagram" or symbolic equivalent functions and the actual realization with integrated transistors.

For those who understand how to read schematics, this helps to explain the finer details on how it works with voltage level shifting and input biasing. For those who want to learn, it helps to show how it is done.

[image]

Comment: This is awesome, i will check this.

Answer (score 6):

In general, we use triangles to represent amplifiers. Whether they're digital logic buffers, op-amps, RF amplifiers, or whatever, depends on the context of the circuit.

In this case the two amplifiers on the left are comparators.

They produce a logic high output when the positive input is at a higher voltage than the negative input, and a logic low output otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

The triangle symbol is **an amplifier**.

- The left ones are differential input amplifiers, and as the output goes into a digital block, they are comparators.
- The right one is an inverter with the inverter circle on input instead of output. There is not functional difference between the two variants.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I would say they are comparator symbols or not gates with an enable, but most likely comparators that are outputing high if one signal is higher than the other.

The one on the right is a not gate or inverter.